# On a Jetty server how do you disable directory listing, if your servlet only maps to a particular url pattern?

Tags: java, servlets, ant, jetty

I have a .war application that is deployed by my Jetty server. When I access it I'm able to view the directory structure by navigating to say localhost/MyServlet/folder. I have tried to include the following in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.something.path.my.class.Servlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

When I rebuild my .war and run it I can still access the directory structure in my browser. This is what I would expect because I also have the following defined in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I know that it's not the servlet that's causing this, it's Jetty that is handling and returning these directory structures. I can't find any way of turning this off within Jetty however. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually discovered that I could set this on the code base of my WebApp itself. When the web application context is setup in my java code, I can simply set it as an initiation parameter:

```
WebAppContext webApp = new WebAppContext();
webApp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory listing is a feature of the `DefaultServlet` (specified as part of the Servlet Spec).

This is a Web Container feature, and as such, it cannot be controlled / edited / configured from within the WebApp itself.

But all is not lost, you'll need to deploy your web application using the Jetty XML deployable techniques, and specify an alternate `defaultsDescriptor`

```xml
<New id="sebWebAppContext"  class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/sebapp</Set>
  <Set name="war">./wars/sebapp.war</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor">/home/seb/jetty/sebwebdefaults.xml</Set>
  .
  .
</New>
```

Where you take a copy of your `${jetty.home}/etc/webdefault.xml` and copy it to your location of choice (do not edit/modify/delete/change any content in the `${jetty.home}` directory).

Set the [`dirAllowed` parameter to `false`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.5.v20151012/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L143-L146).

Answer (score 0):

Your original point does not work because it cannot override the option in the webdefault.xml.  Having said that I usually just edit that file to disable listing globally for that jetty instance:
i.e.   within  webdefault.xml

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple solution if you just want he content to be hidden is to add a blank (or message of your choice) index.html file into that directory, as this will be picked up be default.